# Debian shutdown takes a long time (RAID/crypt related)

Tags: linux, debian, encryption, raid, shutdown

I'm running Debian Jessie and recently my shutdown has been taking a long time. When I

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

I'm sent to a blank screen except for a blinking cursor which sits for ~1 minute. It then flashes something like

> "Cannot finalize remaining filesystems and devices, giving up"

and then shuts off. I get this behavior even when powering down from a terminal with no X server running.

I suspect the problem has to do with my full disk encryption, possibly in conjunction with my software RAID configuration. I have three RAID0 arrays (for /boot, /, and swap) and two RAID1 arrays (for an unmounted /private, and /home). All the RAID devices are encrypted except for the /boot one, and I additionally have an encrypted external /data drive.

Shutdown used to be near-instant until an update about a week ago.

Is this a known issue and are there any fixes? I don't even know how to troubleshoot this issue.

EDIT: My `/etc/fstab` looks like

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/md1_crypt /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/md0 during installation
UUID=3cc83648-0151-412a-925e-415493da44a5 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/sda1_crypt /data           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/md4_crypt /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/md2_crypt none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
/dev/sdd1       /media/usb0     auto    rw,user,noauto  0       0
```

and my `/etc/crypttab` looks like

```
md1_crypt UUID=fbeb3085-5663-4dea-8fa9-97aaadf25e85 none luks
md2_crypt /dev/md2 /dev/urandom cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=256,swap
md4_crypt UUID=38e980ca-e8d3-4e57-9263-61bc4ed3b51c none luks
sda1_crypt UUID=cb5e3ddf-cd97-414d-9a17-7c932ef32484 none luks
```